# Hide blocks in Susy

Tags: sass, susy-compass

Looking at the [susy site](http://susy.oddbird.net/), how does it hide `.secondary` when getting at a breakpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from the [GutHub source](https://github.com/ericam/susy/blob/master/docs/source/stylesheets/_layout.scss#L33) for the site (with other styles removed):

```
.guides, .tutorial {   
  .secondary { display: none; } // secondary starts hidden

  @include at-breakpoint($break) {    
    .secondary { display: block; } // secondary becomes visible at breakpoint
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
@include at-breakpoint($break)  {
                                 .secondary { display: none; }
                             }
```